# Easiest way to update a large vector dataset

Tags: qgis

About 6 months ago, I downloaded a county dataset of all of the parcels contained in that particular county, which was a zip file with about 78,000+ records. I added it to my QGIS as a vector file. I have a map with map views and print views using this dataset layer and all of the symbology set up exactly the way I like it. I called this layer "Land Use".

Today, I downloaded an updated file from the county, the new file has all the same attributes obviously, just with updated information. I added it to my map called, by default "parcels".

I was just going to delete the existing "Land Use" layer, and add the new "parcel" layer, but that would require me building all my definition queries, rules, and symbology all over again. I know there has to be a better way.

I tried opening the Attribute Table in "Land Use" and deleting all of the content, then opening the "parcels" table and copying all the data and then pasting it in the "Land Use" table since all attributes are the same. That worked for about the first 25,000 records (out of 78,000) which took about 15 minutes but then QGIS bogs down and stops responding, and my laptop gets hot and slow.

Surely there is a better way to update the data without adding a new layer, I just am not sure how to go about it. I am fairly inexperienced with QGIS/GIS in general.

Comment: Why not just delete the actual dataset (not the layer in QGIS) and save the updated dataset with the same name as the old one?

Comment: So I opened Windows Explorer and found the parcels zip file, extracted, and grabbed the .dbf file. I copied it and pasted it in the location of the original "Land Use" folder with the same name, overwriting the data. However it didn't change anything when I reopened.

Comment: No, if you're going to replace a shapefile, you replace all the files. You may need to re-open QGIS afterwards.

Comment: Also, you  can't replace a shapefile, while it is opened in QGIS. Close your project, replace your data, open the project, done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain both datasets:
Start with creating a backup of your working QGIS project
(Project > Save As)

1 Extract the complete updated dataset to a location of your liking, say subfolder "202011", so you do not overwrite your original dataset.

2 In QGIS in your project layer pane, select the original layer "Land Use", rightclick and select "duplicate layer". A layer named "Land Use copy" will show up.

3 Rename the copied layer to something useful like "Land Use 202011".

4 Rightclick layer "Land Use 202011" and select "Change Data Source...", navigate to subfolder "202011", and select your updated extracted .shp file.

5 done, now you (should) have two working versions of your dataset. In layer properties information, you can see which dataset is actually used in your layer.

6 If you do not want to create a new layer, just do the "Change Data Source..." on the original "Land Use" layer, navigate to subfolder "202011", and select your updated extracted .shp file.